# using IP Webcam for images and passing the url to API

Tags: android, ip-camera, imageurl

I'm using IP Webcam app in my android phone to use it as an IP camera and I'm using another android phone to run my app that recognizes faces using Kairos API. I'm using the IP Webcam app and the image is streamed at a url which is something like:
"http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/photo.jpg" and I am able to view the image through this url on all the devices, however the API that I'm using has a recognize function that takes image url as one of it's parameters but when I'm using the streamed image URL, it doesn't work. I tried figuring out what's happening through logs but all I could see was that it threw a SocketTimeoutException(read time out) and tried solutions for it from SO but nothing worked, any suggestions here?

code:

```
    public void getUrlText(){

        try{
            url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/photo.jpg");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable timedTask = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getUrlText();
            handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 1000);
    }};
```

and this is inside onCreate method:

```
        getUrlText();
        handler.post(timedTask);
        recognizePhotoKairos(Uri.parse(url.toString()), userPhoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ip webcam make sure your all the devices connected to same server.
Second thing is that you have to refresh the url again and again in order to get the latest image. I think this is your main problem in refreshing the url. I suggest you to use handler for this, which wait for a particular time and then refresh the url again or api in your case.
[Read more about handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)
I am adding the my source code of a project where i start the handler again and again

public class CounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textView;
private boolean started = false;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

    textView=findViewById(R.id.points);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My:Tag");
```

// screen stays on in this section

```
    start();


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            final String URL="http://172.16.16.108:8080/wallgame/api/game_points";

            StringRequest request=
                    new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);

                                        JSONObject data=object.getJSONObject("data");


                                        int points=Integer.parseInt(data.getString("game_points"));

                                        textView.setText(points+"");

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(CounterActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    );
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(CounterActivity.this);
            queue.add(request);

        }
    },1000);
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        final String URL="http://172.16.16.108:8080/wallgame/api/game_points";

        StringRequest request=
                new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {
                                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);

                                    JSONObject data=object.getJSONObject("data");


                                    int points=Integer.parseInt(data.getString("game_points"));

                                    textView.setText(points+"");

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(CounterActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                );
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(CounterActivity.this);
        queue.add(request);
        start();
    }
};
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    started = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    if (wl.isHeld())
        wl.release();
}
public void start(){
    started = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500);
}
```

}

Comment: I tried all these, but nothing worked. I have added some code here, can you please see if there's anything missing?

Comment: You are not stating the handler again. You just start it once. Handler basically waits till the time is over so that you can do your work. You have to start handler again and again and make a infinite loop so that you got the latest picture.

Comment: I have edit my answer with a sample code where i start the handler again and again.